# When can I cherry-pick

Tags: github, cherry-pick

I pose this scenario:

I have two branches in the upstream repo:

develop

master

My task is to create two pull requests, one against develop, and one against master.

So i create two branches in my local:

```
git checkout -b develop-local
git checkout -b master-local
```

Now for some reason, I made the (identical) changes in both local repos manually, push to my origin and created pull requests for each.

If I am now required to create another change in develop-local on top of the already-made changes, can I cherry-pick this latest develop-local commit over to master-local?

How does cherry pick determine when cherry-picking is allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the extra commit you made to `develop` locally is just a regular commit (and not something like a merge commit), there is no reason why cherry picking should not work here:

```
# from master (local)
git cherry-pick develop
```

The above command will actually make a *new* commit on top of `master`, functionally corresponding to the HEAD commit in `develop` which you just made.  You may now push your local `master` branch to GitHub, and the pull request should be updated automatically.